# What should I do with a temp np ndarray created in the cython PyObject in __dealloc__

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to change some code and have to create a np.ndarray in a cython class

```
cdef class T:

    def __cinit__(self, X):
        # copy a memory space by the numpy way
        cdef np.ndarray temp = np.ndarray(shape=X.shape, dtype=X.dtype)
        self.X_fake = <DTYPE_t*> temp.data

    def __dealloc__(self):
        # should I free this?
        free(self.X_fake)
```

I have found nothing in numpy or cython doc. I know if I use malloc to create a DTYPE_t* pointer, it's easy to work, I just wanna know that whether should I free the self.X_fake, or how can I dealloc the temp ndarray, will cython dealloc a numpy class by gc workflow?

Comment: In you special case (when it compiles), I wouldn't touch `X_fake` at all, because it is a dangling pointer as soon as the program is outside of `__cinit__`.

Comment: Use ndarray class to create a memory space instead of malloc. Your answer is that the temp will dealloc after __cinit__, so the pointer will not hold a malloced memory space?

Comment: I wouldn't call it an answer. But yes, this is what will happen. I also would not says that a pointer "holds memory" - it just points to an memory address, which might no longer be accessible and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yes I mean that pointer points to the memory block, but after __cinit__ ends, that memory block will be free, which means it would be malloced to another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ead has pointed out, currently `temp` is an automatic variable that will go out of scope at the end of `__cinit__`. This means that `self.X_fake` will be pointing to nothing, and likely cause you problems. Here's the simplest way to fix your code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

cdef class T:
    cdef np.ndarray temp
    cdef DTYPE_t* X_fake

    def __cinit__(self, X):
        # copy a memory space by the numpy way
        self.temp = np.ndarray(shape=X.shape, dtype=X.dtype)
        self.X_fake = <DTYPE_t*> self.temp.data
```

This way, `temp` will share the lifetime of the `T` instance to which it belongs. You don't need a `__dealloc__`. `temp` will get automatically cleaned up along with everything else in a given instance of `T` when it goes out of scope/gets garbage collected.

Also, you'll know if you have to `free` the memory belonging to a pointer, since in that case you'll have created it with `malloc` in the first place. If you didn't `malloc` it, don't `free` it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know the way to use malloc and free, just don't really know how to deal with ndarray.